# Which book about encryption did Christopher give Alan when he was a child?

Tags: the-imitation-game

In one of the flashbacks in *The Imitation Game* that show Alan's childhood, Christopher gave him a book about encryption.

What is the name of that book?

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1629/49).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book, *A Guide to Codes and Ciphers*, is likely a prop. The contents shown, however, are clearly identical to those from Simon Singh's 1999 book *The Code Book*.

*The Code Book* contains a history of ciphers and code-breaking, including basic ciphers as shown, as well as an extensive history of Alan Turing and his work at Bletchley Park (including the transcript of the letter sent to Churchill and the actual crossword published in the Daily Telegraph).

It's a very good book, and I imagine it would have been a very effective production reference.

[image: reference comparing a poor screenshot of the film to images from The Code Book]

Comment: So...it was a book from...THE FUTURE...about...HIMSELF! Puts a whole new sci-fi spin on the film! :)

Answer (score 7):

"A Guide to Codes and Ciphers". Whether it's a real book or a movie prop, I do not know.

[image]